# Find the dbpedia uri for a given place

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, ontology

I need your help with the following situation.

I have a local relational database that contains information about several places in a city. These places could be any kind of attraction: Museum, a cathedral, or even a square.

As an example I have information about "Square Victoria" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victoria_Square,_Montreal)

A simple search in google gave me the wikipedia URL above. But I want to be able to do it programmatically.

For each place in the database I have also its category (square, museum, church, ....). These categories are local only and do not match any standardized categorization.

My goal is to improve this database by associating each place to its dbpedia URI.

My question is what is the best way to do that? I have some theoretical background about Semantic Web technologies but I don't have yet the practice skills to determine how to do that.

More specific questions:

1. Is it possible to determine the dbpedia URI using sparql only?
2. If it is not possible to do it with sparql only, what other technologies would I need to be able to accomplish that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would recommend, if you have not done it yet, to have a look at wikidata. This project is a semantic extension to wikipedia, but contrary to dbpedia, the data is not extracted from wikipedia, it is created by contributors, and therefore appears (or will appear as the project is still growing) to be more relevant.

The service offers many [solutions to access data](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Data_access) (including a [Sparql endpoint](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Data_access)), and it's main advantage is that the underlying software is mediawiki, same used for wikipedia and other Wikimedia foundation projects. The mediawiki API offers an Opensearch option that should allow you to search more efficiently that Sparql queries.

Putting everything together, I think it might be worth having a look at wikidata + wikipedia API to get pivot data to align you local database.

No direct answer but I hope that will help.

Comment: Even if it is not a direct answer as you choose to describe your answer, the information you provided is very interesting. Thank you for that Sylvain.